Feedback vertex set algorithm problem
Problem Context
I am working on solving the Minimum Feedback Vertex Set (MinFVS) problem on a 2D geometric graph. A geometric graph consists of vertices defined as points in a 2D plane, with edges existing between two points if their Euclidean distance is smaller than a given threshold.
The goal is to find a minimal set of vertices (FVS) to remove such that the remaining graph is acyclic (a forest). This is for a graded project, where performance is evaluated based on the average score (size of FVS) across multiple runs, aiming for a score lower than 83%.
Current Algorithm
The provided algorithm consists of the following steps:

Greedy Approach: Attempts to remove vertices with high degrees iteratively until the remaining graph is acyclic.
Local Search: Improves the initial greedy solution by applying a "remove 2, add 1" heuristic.
Iterative Improvement: Repeats the process three times to find better solutions.
Key Issues:
The solution often gets stuck in local minima, resulting in suboptimal FVS sizes.
The algorithm's greedy and local search steps do not effectively explore the solution space.
Performance needs to be improved to achieve a smaller FVS (score < 83%).

Code
Below is the core implementation.
package algorithms;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class DefaultTeam {

  public ArrayList<Point> calculFVS(ArrayList<Point> points, int edgeThreshold) {
    ArrayList<Point> result = (ArrayList<Point>)points.clone();

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
      ArrayList<Point> fvs = localSearch(greedy(points,edgeThreshold),points,edgeThreshold);

      System.out.println("MAIN. Current sol: " + result.size() + ". Found next sol: "+fvs.size());

      if (fvs.size()<result.size()) result = fvs;
    }

    return result;
    //return greedy(points,edgeThreshold);
  }

  private ArrayList<Point> greedy(ArrayList<Point> pointsIn, int edgeThreshold) {
    ArrayList<Point> points = (ArrayList<Point>)pointsIn.clone();
    ArrayList<Point> result = (ArrayList<Point>)pointsIn.clone();


    for (int i=0;i<100;i++) {
      Collections.shuffle(points, new Random(System.nanoTime()));
      ArrayList<Point> rest = removeDuplicates(points);
      ArrayList<Point> fvs = new ArrayList<Point>();

      while (!isSolution(fvs,points,edgeThreshold)) {
        Point choosenOne=rest.get(0);
        for (Point p: rest) if (degree(p,rest,edgeThreshold)>degree(choosenOne,rest,edgeThreshold)) choosenOne=p;
        fvs.add(choosenOne);
        rest.removeAll(fvs);
      }

//      System.out.println("GR. Current sol: " + result.size() + ". Found next sol: "+fvs.size());

      if (fvs.size()<result.size()) result = fvs;

    }

    return result;
  }
  private ArrayList<Point> localSearch(ArrayList<Point> firstSolution, ArrayList<Point> points, int edgeThreshold) {
    ArrayList<Point> current = removeDuplicates(firstSolution);
    ArrayList<Point> next = (ArrayList<Point>)current.clone();

    System.out.println("LS. First sol: " + current.size());

    do {
      current = next;
      next = remove2add1(current, points,edgeThreshold);
      System.out.println("LS. Current sol: " + current.size() + ". Found next sol: "+next.size());
    } while (score(current)>score(next));

    System.out.println("LS. Last sol: " + current.size());
    return next;

//  return current;
  }
  private ArrayList<Point> remove2add1(ArrayList<Point> candidate, ArrayList<Point> points, int edgeThreshold) {
    ArrayList<Point> test = removeDuplicates(candidate);
    long seed = System.nanoTime();
    Collections.shuffle(test, new Random(seed));
    ArrayList<Point> rest = removeDuplicates(points);
    rest.removeAll(test);

    for (int i=0;i<test.size();i++) {
      for (int j=i+1;j<test.size();j++) {
        Point q = test.remove(j);
        Point p = test.remove(i);

        for (Point r: rest) {
          test.add(r);
          if (isSolution(test,points,edgeThreshold)) return test;
          test.remove(r);
        }

        test.add(i,p);
        test.add(j,q);
      }
    }

    return candidate;
  }
  private boolean isSolution(ArrayList<Point> candidateIn, ArrayList<Point> pointsIn, int edgeThreshold) {
    ArrayList<Point> candidate = removeDuplicates(candidateIn);
    ArrayList<Point> rest = removeDuplicates(pointsIn);
    rest.removeAll(candidate);
    ArrayList<Point> visited = new ArrayList<Point>();

    while (!rest.isEmpty()) {
      visited.clear();
      visited.add(rest.remove(0));
      for (int i=0;i<visited.size();i++) {
        for (Point p: rest) if (isEdge(visited.get(i),p,edgeThreshold)) {
          for (Point q: visited) if (!q.equals(visited.get(i)) && isEdge(p,q,edgeThreshold)) return false;
          visited.add(p);
        }
        rest.removeAll(visited);
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
  private ArrayList<Point> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<Point> points) {
    ArrayList<Point> result = (ArrayList<Point>)points.clone();
    for (int i=0;i<result.size();i++) {
      for (int j=i+1;j<result.size();j++) if (result.get(i).equals(result.get(j))) {
        result.remove(j);
        j--;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
  private boolean isEdge(Point p, Point q, int edgeThreshold) {
    return p.distance(q)<edgeThreshold;
  }
  private int degree(Point p, ArrayList<Point> points, int edgeThreshold) {
    int degree=-1;
    for (Point q: points) if (isEdge(p,q,edgeThreshold)) degree++;
    return degree;
  }
  private int score(ArrayList<Point> candidate) {
    return candidate.size();
  }
}


Specific Question
What modifications can I make to this algorithm to improve its performance in finding a smaller Feedback Vertex Set?
Suggestions can include:

Enhancing the greedy or local search steps.
Introducing new heuristics or optimization techniques.
Algorithmic changes to better explore the solution space.

I am particularly interested in practical ways to:

Escape local minima in the local search phase.
Optimize vertex selection in the greedy phase.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I don't think it is reasonable to expect that anyone will read your code.  Is it crucial for your question?  If not, please remove it.

Surely you are aware that the problem is NP-complete (on unit disk graphs)?  Did you consider using an off-the-shelf SAT solver?

There is a simple preprocessing procedure that might remove many vertices from your initial graph: 1. If there is a vertex $v$ containing a self-loop, remove $v$ and decrease $k$ by one.
2. If there is a vertex of degree at most one, remove it.
3. If there is a vertex of degree two, remove it and connect its two neighbors by an edge.
4. If two vertices are connected by more than two edges, replace these edges with a double edge.  From Linear-time Kernelization for Feedback Vertex Set, Iwata.

There are many graphs such that the cardinality of minimum feedback vertex set is greater than $0.83n$, where $n$ is the graph order. The most simple example is complete graph $K_n$. It appears when all points fall into a circle of radius $d/2$, where $d$ is threshold distance. If such case is impossible it makes sense to describe missing constraints.
